Jetpack Compose TextField Not Showing 'text' Property in LambdaTest/Appium Automation Testing
Description:
I am working on an Android application that utilizes both XML and Jetpack Compose for its UI components. The application runs correctly during normal use, but I am encountering issues with automation testing using LambdaTest and Appium.
Problem:
In the Jetpack Compose sections of the application, specifically within TextField components, the text property is not being displayed in the testing tools. This text property is crucial for users to input data into the text fields during the tests. Moreover, the TextField is being identified as a TextView in the view hierarchy during testing. Additionally, when the keyboard expands for user input, the view hierarchy shows an additional view for the value being input by the user. The data entered in the TextField is also becoming the name of this TextView.
I have also tried to reproduce this issue in a new project with a simple Jetpack Compose TextField, but the text property was still not showing up in the testing tools.
Details:

The application works as expected when run normally.
The issue only arises during automation testing with LambdaTest.
The TextField components in Jetpack Compose do not expose the text property needed for the automation tests to interact with the text input.
The TextField is being identified as a TextView in the view hierarchy.
When the keyboard expands for user input, an additional view appears in the hierarchy, representing the input value.
The entered data in the TextField is being used as the name of the TextView in the view hierarchy.
I have added testTags and contentDescriptions to the components, but the problem persists.
Even a new Jetpack Compose project with a simple TextField exhibits the same issue with the text property not showing up in the testing tools.

Snippet of the code which also is representing edit text in my Application. 1st part of the code
2nd part of the code
Component Definition:
 TextField(
        isError = isError ?: false,
        value = value,
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        enabled = isEnable ?: true,
        modifier = modifier
            .height(50.dp)
            .testTag(label)
            .semantics {
                contentDescription = "Input field for $label"
                set(SemanticsProperties.EditableText, AnnotatedString(value))
                text = AnnotatedString(value)
                testTagsAsResourceId= true
            },
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        textStyle = TextStyle(
            color = colorResource(id = R.color.colorBlackShadow),
            fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.notosans_regular)),
            fontSize = 14.sp
        ),
        keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
        label = {
            TextNormalSmall(
                text = label,
                modifier = Modifier,
                textStyle = TextStyle(
                    colorResource(id = R.color.colorBlackShadow),
                    fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.notosans_regular))
                ),
            )
        },
        placeholder = {
            Text(
                text = placeholder ?: "",
                modifier = Modifier
            )
        },
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
            focusedIndicatorColor = colorResource(id = R.color.colorAccent),
            cursorColor = Color.Gray
        ),
        trailingIcon = trailingIcon
    )
},

Explanation:

The TextFieldComponent is a custom composable function used throughout the UI to handle text input fields.
The TextFieldComponent uses Modifier.testTag() and Modifier.semantics() to set test tags and semantic properties for accessibility and testing purposes.
Despite setting EditableText and text in the semantics properties, the text property is not visible in the automation testing tools.
The TextField is being identified as a TextView in the view hierarchy during testing.
An additional view appears in the view hierarchy representing the input value when the keyboard expands.

This is how its showing in lambdatest when I click the field with UI inspector
Questions:

How can I ensure that the text property of Jetpack Compose TextField is accessible during automation tests with LambdaTest?
Are there specific configurations or workarounds in Jetpack Compose to make properties like text visible to testing tools?
What are best practices for making Jetpack Compose components testable in UI automation frameworks like LambdaTest and Appium?

Any guidance or solutions to make the text property visible in the testing tools and correctly identify the TextField would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
